# 301 Redirect For SSL URL

Tags: redirect

301 redirect has me completely lost and confused so I would really appreciate if someone can help me with the code.

My website is [www.dfwpcrepairs.com](https://www.dfwpcrepairs.com) I recently purchased the SSL for my site and changed the site from plain HTML site to Wordpress. I kept all the URLs structures the same as they were before and used a plugin to keep the .html extensions in Wordpress for every URL/page on my site.

So Google Analytic tells me that I have a redundant URLs which I assume it is the non www and the www version of my site.

I want to redirect everything to the www/SSL version of my site/URL. Can someone please help me with the code for this?

I would greatly appreciate this.

Regards,

Rnaderpo

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a plugin for this instead of hacking into `.htaccess` file.

I personally use `WordPress HTTPS (SSL)` you can use any other you like.